# How can I save a Tensorflow Core model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, model, save

I'm a beginner in Tensorflow and I found this neural network for binary classification which is giving me decent results, I would like to know after I run the session how can I save the model? I already try from the official website but nothing is working.

```
class AnnMLP():

def train(self,X_input,y_input,test,range_iteration,learning_rate): X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,27]) Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])

# input
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([27,60], seed=0), name='weight1')
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([60], seed=0), name='bias1')
layer1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X,W1) + b1)
dropout_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4)
layer1=dropout_layer(layer1)

# hidden1
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([60,60], seed=0), name='weight2')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([60], seed=0), name='bias2')
layer2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(layer1,W2) + b2)

dropout_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4)
layer2=dropout_layer(layer2)

# hidden2
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([60,90], seed=0), name='weight3')
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([90], seed=0), name='bias3')
layer3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(layer2,W3) + b3)
dropout_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4)
layer3=dropout_layer(layer3)

# output
W4 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([90,1], seed=0), name='weight4')
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1], seed=0), name='bias4')

logits = tf.matmul(layer3,W4) + b4
hypothesis = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)


cost_i = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=Y)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost_i)
train =tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
#train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(cost) train = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

prediction = tf.cast(hypothesis > 0.5, dtype=tf.float32)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(prediction, Y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, dtype=tf.float32))
print("\n============Processing============")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(range_iteration):
        sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: X_input, Y: y_input})

        if step % 1000 == 0:

          loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={X: X_input, Y: y_input})
          print("Step: {:5}\tLoss: {:.3f}\tAcc: {:.2%}".format(step, loss, acc))



        train_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: X_input, Y: y_input})
        if test == True:
          test_acc,test_predict,test_correct = sess.run([accuracy,prediction,correct_prediction], feed_dict={X: X_test, Y: y_test})

return test_predict
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow provides privilege to load and restore entire model and checkpoints. For more details find the link [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load).

Tensorflow < 2

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run()
  # Do some work with the model.

  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```

Tensorflow > 2

```
# Create and train a new model instance.
model = create_model()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)

# Save the entire model to a HDF5 file.
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow provides privilege to load and restore entire model and checkpoints

Tensorflow < 2

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run()
# Do some work with the model.

# Save the variables to disk.
save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```

Tensorflow>2

```
# Create and train a new model instance.
model = create_model()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)

# Save the entire model to a HDF5 file.
model.save('my_model.h5'
```